# Can I downgrade my google play services version?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-support-library

I'm using 10.2.0 version of Google Play Services, how can I downgrade it to 10.0.1 or earlier so I can support down to API 9 devices.

Comment: change the number

Comment: Change it under dependencies in gradle file. But why? It is better to always stay updated....

Answer (score -1):

Yes You can downgrade but you have to do changes accordingly.